# Sequential Search 2 Lists

Tags: python-3.x, search, linear-search

So for homework we were asked to write a function that takes 2 lists as an input and use a sequential/linear search to go through them and if any name appeared in both lists to append that name to a new list. For the actual assignment two classes are specified as VoterList and VoterName, thus not allowing us to use 'in' and only VoterNames can be appended to a VoterList. (This task is going to be developed into finding people who voted twice in two different voting booths for an election).

So I have written a function that seems to work when I pass in 3-4 person long lists but I'm not sure that it is actually a sequential search working how it should be. Would be awesome for some advice. Cheers

```
def fraud_detect_seq(first_booth_voters, second_booth_voters):
    fraud = []    

    length_first = len(first_booth_voters)
    length_second = len(second_booth_voters)

    first_booth_position = 0
    second_booth_position = 0


    while first_booth_position < length_first:
        name_comparison = first_booth_voters[first_booth_position]

        if second_booth_position == length_second:
            first_booth_position += 1
            second_booth_position = 0

        elif second_booth_voters[second_booth_position] == name_comparison:
            fraud.append(second_booth_voters[second_booth_position])
            first_booth_position += 1
            second_booth_position += 1

        elif second_booth_voters[second_booth_position] != name_comparison:
            second_booth_position += 1


    print(fraud)

fraud_detect_seq(['Jackson', 'Dylan', 'Alice'],['Jackson', 'ylan', 'Alice'])
```

Gets the output:

```
['Jackson', 'Alice']
```

Which is correct. But I feel like I'm not doing it right.

Comment: why not use `in`? Iterate through the first list, checking if its items are in the second.

Comment: not allowed to use in :)

Comment: Then mimic its functionality -- which will add a second (inner) loop

Comment: The way I have written this code seems to be giving the desired output though? Or will this function break with larger lists?

Comment: It seems on the verbose side. For one thing -- why use indices and length at all? `for name in list1: #check if also in list2` is more idiomatic. Even without using `in` you should be able to get a solution in about 6 lines of code.

Comment: Okay thank you. Working on it now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87318/discussion-between-mikey-and-john-coleman).

Comment: Thank you for your help John. I got it in exactly 6 lines of code haha.  What I was trying to do was the last part of the assignment which was a merge sort of types! Trust me for making things harder than they are :P

Answer (score 0):

```
def fraud_detect_seq(first_booth_voters, second_booth_voters):
    fraud = []

    for voter in first_booth_voters:
        if voter in second_booth_voters:
           fraud.append(voter)
```

This is a really simple way of checking if they are in both lists. There isn't a wrong way to write the program but since you're using python you might as well us the most "pythonic". For loops are incredibly useful in python for checking membership in lists.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response but we aren't allowed to use pythons 'in' as stated in the original post :)

Comment: If an OP clearly indicates that something is homework you should try to not go beyond giving hints.